# Laravel Update hasMany relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've got the following:

**MirrorModule Model**

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function xous()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Xou');
}
```

**Xou model**

```
public function mirrorModule()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MirrorModule');
}
```

Basic stuff here. All I want is update the just like the sync method in ManyToMany which takes `id's` and figures out the rest for you.

I've got an array coming in looks like this:

[image]

**What I have tried**

```
   if ($request->has('xous')) {
            $arr = [];
            foreach ($data['xous'] as $value) {
            // $arr[] = [
            //     'id' => $value['id'],
            // ];
            // $arr[] = $value;
           $xous = Xou::findOrFail($value['id']);
          $mm = $mirrorModule->xous()->where('mirror_module_id',$mirrorModule['id'])->get(); 
          $mm->update() // ?? or save()  save returns error 

        }
    }
```

I also looked over this [article](https://medium.com/@amithgotamey/laravel-5-2-sync-method-for-has-many-relationship-3e279d6dd07d) to implement my own sync method, but can't get it work.

Any ideas? Other approaches are welcome as well.

Comment: what do you want to do, save `$xous` to `$mm` ?

Comment: @rkj Yes. Basically update the $mm model with the array in the pic

Comment: you can use `$mirrorModule->xous()->save($xous);`

Comment: @rkj I tried this, it returns 'must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given'. Unless I am not getting your idea here?

Comment: use it after `$xous = Xou::findOrFail($value['id']);` and then `$mirrorModule->xous()->save($xous);`

Comment: @rkj I see. What about if I receive an array without the existing objects? It's not updating just like (as I mentioned) the sync method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177002/discussion-between-rkj-and-user3641381).

Answer (score 1):

Use `whereIn` on an array of ids:

```
$ids = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item['id']:
}, $request->get('xous'));

$mirrorModule->xous()->whereIn('id', $ids)->update(...);
```

Comment: `update` takes either 2 parameters, a field name and the value to update, or a single parameter as an associative array of field => value pairs.

Comment: This method is not working for me. `$mirrorModule->xous()->whereIn('id', $ids)->update(['mirror_module_id' => $mirrorModule]);`  Nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have the models `$fillable` property set with the attributes you're updating?

Comment: Yes. Yet nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `->update()` on Collection object, `->get()` returns a Collection object, not a model or a query.

What you need to do (if I understood correctly what you want) is

```
 if ($request->has('xous')) {
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($data['xous'] as $value) {
        // $arr[] = [
        //     'id' => $value['id'],
        // ];
        // $arr[] = $value;
       $xous = Xou::findOrFail($value['id']);
       $mm = $mirrorModule->xous()->where('mirror_module_id',$mirrorModule['id'])->update([
           'attribute_to_update' => 'some_value'
       ]); 

    }
}
```

which will basically update all rows in database with that `mirror_module_id` with some value.

Answer (score 0):

Please, avoid executing queries within the loop. findOrFail accepts array of ids, so you can extract ids to temp variable, and then do bulk update.
Update method accepts array of arguments you want to change (update).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the way:

```
 $category->posts()->update(['category_id' => $newCatId]);
```